# Unable to install vim on Ubuntu 14.04: "Package 'vim' has no installation candidate"

Tags: software-installation, vim

```
sudo apt-get install vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package vim is a virtual package provided by:
  vim-nox 2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3
  vim-gtk 2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3
  vim-athena 2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'vim' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 0):

`apt-get install -y vim-version`

--WHERE "version" is whatever your machine says. In your case... vim-nox 2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3 OR vim-gtk 2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3 OR vim-athena 2:7.4.052-1ubuntu3 
One of those 3. Pick one

Comment: yes i got what you have given me the suggestion but it is not working even though i try to install those i also did sudo apt-get update